# Distorted KML Ground Overlay in QGIS

Tags: qgis, kml, google-earth

Still learning my way around QGIS and ran into an odd issue this evening. I'm using a program called Radio Mobile Deluxe to generate RF models.  It exports images as KML ground overlays.  I then bring the KML into QGIS, then georeference the raster.

However, this evening, I noticed that things didn't look quite right.  I should be looking at perfectly square objects (8000x8000 meters and a 800x800 pixel raster).

The overlay imports perfectly into Earth, but when I bring it into QGIS, it's measuring out 10km wide.  However, when I compare visual features in the imagery basemap and roads, everything looks dead on.  I'm really not sure what I'm looking at here, if it's a problem, or how to fix it.

I'm using QGIS 2.18.4, the project CRS is 4326.  Not quite sure what other information I should provide.

Here's a screenshot, showing a very square object in Earth and a not-so-square object in QGIS, along with the N/S/E/W coordinates generated by Radio Mobile.

[image]

Here's a sample KML file I created in Earth and loaded into QGIS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>foo.kml</name>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin_hl">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.3</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff0000ff</color>
            <width>3.5</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <fill>0</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="m_ylw-pushpin">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin_hl</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff0000ff</color>
            <width>3.5</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <fill>0</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
        <name>Untitled Polygon</name>
        <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        <Polygon>
            <tessellate>1</tessellate>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                    <coordinates>
                        -79.22887,38.08849,0 -79.13737,38.08849,0 -79.13737,38.08849,0 -79.13737,38.16048,0 -79.22887,38.16048,0 -79.22887,38.16048,0 -79.22887,38.16048,0 -79.22887,38.08849,0 
                    </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

EDIT: Here's what the raster looks like (after converting to polygon and removing the background).

[image]

When I spot-check the overlay down to the pixel, it's identical between QGIS and Earth.  Accurate enough for modeling RF signals, which tend to get pretty fuzzy in the real world.

Comment: What is the layer CRS set to? Could be a georeferencing error? Sometimes when I come across something weird like that I georeference the image again and double check the numbers I type in. Usually that fixes the issue.

Comment: I had to restart my project several times before settling on EPSG: 4326, which for good or bad, I find easiest to work with at this time.

Comment: While 4326 seemed to work well, it looks like I'll have to use 3857 for my project (at least until I find something better).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're having the expected behaviour.

**Google Earth** does not distort your image while QGIS is ! Due to it's 3D Globe, Google Earth can be equal of angle AND area (disclaimer: unless you have a 3d screen, projection onto your 2d screen will of course distort your angle too, but that is not noticeable on that scale).

As coordinates on the globe are always 3D, **QGIS** needs to project them somehow onto the map on your 2D screen. Thus, the image will always be distorted. The projection commonly used for showing WGS84 (EPSG:4326) coordinates is [Plate Carree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) (longitude=x, latitude=y). If you're looking on the whole Globe using this projection, the further you go north or south the more distorted it will be.

[image]

(*[Picture: Eric Gaba – Wikimedia Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection#/media/File:Tissot_indicatrix_world_map_equirectangular_proj.svg)*)

This is why a lot of CRS exist, most of them suitable only for one specific region of the earth where it shows only very little distortion.

**What you can do:**

Change the projection of your map in QGIS to the [UTM Zone of your region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system) (or maybe play around using Mercator (EPSG:3857) and you will have your *almost* perfect square.

[image: EPSG:3857]

---

[image: EPSG:4326]

Comment: Thank you so much for that.  At first, I was discounting the difference as a combination of illusion and projection differences.  For some reason, this particular object really stood out to me.

The part I really don't understand is why 8km in Earth is 10km in QGIS.  I tested on 16 and 32km, which measured out to 20 and 40km respectively.