# UTM to WGS84 in QGIS 3.18 circle not round

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wgs84, utm

I am using QGIS 3.18.

I have a GeoJSON file with circles in UTM CRS. I exported it to WGS84 and my circles became not round, more like an ellipse.

What is the problem?

Comment: That's correct, circles look like ellipses in plate carrée projection https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection.

Comment: About similar question with an answer here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/235044/distorted-kml-ground-overlay-in-qgis/235057

Comment: You reinvented the [Tissot's indicatrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissot%27s_indicatrix?wprov=sfla1 )